# Which version of Xcode does xcodebuild use?

Tags: xcode4, continuous-integration, hudson, xcodebuild, xcode3.2

I have installed both Xcode 3.2 and Xcode 4.0.2 on the same machine, which uses Hudson for automated CI (continuous integration) builds. When I say that both were installed, what I mean by that is that I can use both Xcode 3 and Xcode 4 simultaneously or interchangeably. They both exist on the machine, as I did a custom install for Xcode 4 without overwriting Xcode 3 (supposedly).

- Do command line calls to 'xcodebuild' invoke Xcode 3 or Xcode 4?

  - Does that question even make sense? Someone who may or may not be knowledgable on the topic is requesting that some projects be built with 3 and some with 4.
- If so, how do I force it to use 3 or 4?

  - alternatively, is there a separate location where Xcode 3's 'xcodebuild' is stored vs. where Xcode4's 'xcodebuild' is stored? If there is, I can just use a different path in my build script.

Comment: found it! by default, xcodebuild is stored in Developer/usr/bin. I have Xcode4 stored  separately in a folder called Xcode4 so the xcodebuild path for xcodebuild is Xcode4/usr/bin/xcodebuild. This means I will replace 'xcodebuild' in my build script with 'Xcode4/usr/bin/xcodebuild'. I'll let you know if it DOESN'T work.

Comment: What about using 'which -a xcodebuild' to find all the locations in your path where xcodebuild exists. For example in my case this returns '/usr/bin/xcodebuild'. Since this is on the path, issuing 'xcodebuild -version' returns that I have Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can find out what version is xcodebuild using with `xcode-select -print-path`. Also, change to a different version using `xcode-select -switch <path>`

Comment: For me, I had to use sudo to switch path.

Answer (score 50):

Also, to determine which XCode environment is being used, use the command `xcodebuild -version`.

Comment: You may well need to specify where xcodebuild is located, for example if you have Xcode installed, it will probably be here:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

Answer (score 29):

Outside the terminal, you can view and change this in Xcode.

Open **Preferences**, then select the **Locations** tab. Near the bottom, an entry titled **Command Line Tools** labels a dropdown, whose selection corresponds to the version of Xcode used in `xcodebuild`.

You may open this dropdown to select another version of Xcode that you have installed in your `/Applications` or `~/Applications` folder.

[image: Screenshot illustrating the above-described solution.]

---

Interestingly, this panel only says what this pop-up menu does and that it's analogous to `xcode-select` if you've selected a different version of Xcode than the one it's running in.

In case you need it, I also have [a screenshot from what this used to look like in Xcode 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEWpE.png).

Answer (score 1):

One reason we don't use xcode-select is we are not admin or not in sudo list.
we can choose the xcodebuild and not use the default one.

Run `xcode-select -p` and we might get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, and the xcodebuild is in this folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

So if we have installed another Xcode, find the folder and along with that xcodebuild.