# Xcode how to select older version for command line builds

Tags: xcode, gcc

I've got Xcode 7.3 and relevant command line tools, but NVIDIA CUDA compiler currently requires a lower version. I am trying exactly what Apple says to install an older version (7.2). I've downloaded and installed the old (corresponding to 7.2) version of the command line tools, but in Xcode I'm still getting 7.3 as the only option:

[image]

I also try `gcc -v`:

`Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)`

How can I make command line builds use version 7.2?

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7091230